# Parsing different json to one model

Tags: java, json, gson

I have several json models which represent same logic model. e.g:
`{"title":"title1","years":"31"}` and `{"name":"title1","age":31}`

at the moment I make 2 different classes which implement same interface

```
 public class NameModel implements Person {

  @SerializedName("name") private String name;
  @SerializedName("age") private int age;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
}
public class TitleModel implements Person {

  @SerializedName("title") private String title;
  @SerializedName("years") private int years;

  public String getName() {
    return title;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return years;
  }
}
public interface Person {
  String getName();
  int getAge();
}
```

Is this a correct approach to unify different models to one if they are essentially same, but with different field names?

Comment: does it have to be gson? can you use jackson?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher in most of out prject we use gson. However answer for jackson is also valuable

Answer (score 1):

in Jackson, you have the [mixin feature](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations). This allows to add or override annotations at run time.

so we have one target POJO

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and the mixin classes can be interfaces (they never get initialized) with matching setter method signatures and different annotations

```
public interface NameModel
{
    @JsonProperty("name")
    void setName(String name);
    @JsonProperty("age")
    void setAge(int age);
}

public interface TitleModel
{
    @JsonProperty("title")
    void setName(String name);
    @JsonProperty("years")
    void setAge(int age);
}
```

at run-time you can associate one mixin to the target class.  Jackson matches properties and methods by name and takes the annotations from the mixin. overriding any from the target:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nameModelJson = "{\"name\":\"title1\",\"age\":31}";
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(nameModelJson.getBytes())) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Person.class, NameModel.class);
        Person p = mapper.readValue(is, Person.class);
        System.out.println(p.name + " " + p.age);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String titleModelJson = "{\"title\":\"title1\",\"years\":\"31\"}";
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(titleModelJson.getBytes())) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Person.class, TitleModel.class);
        Person p = mapper.readValue(is, Person.class);
        System.out.println(p.name + " " + p.age);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```